# Button press limit

Tags: flutter, button

How to set a limit on button clicks 2 times a day?

I have a button

```
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios), onPressed: () async {

              _CreatePost();
              _showLoaderDialog(context);
            },
            ),
```

and I want the button to be inactive for 24 hours when there are 2 clicks. How can I do this I would appreciate any help.

I tried to find information on many sites but there is very little information, I tried a lot of things but it does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the last button press time to `shared_preferences`  and you just have to calculate the time difference if it is more than 24 hours when you activate the button.

```
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {

  int btnCount = 0;
  String timeString;

  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    btnCount = prefs.getInt('counter');
    time = prefs.getString('action');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Execute Function X'),
          onPressed: () {
            int remaining = differenceTwoTime(target: DateTime.parse(timeString));

            if(remaining > 24){
               log('button is activate');

               if(btnCount == 2){
                 await prefs.setInt('counter', 2);
                 prefs.setString('action');
               }else{
                 btnCount++;
               }
            }else{
               log('button is not activate');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  int differenceTwoTime({DateTime? from, required DateTime target}) {
     return target.difference(from ?? DateTime.now()).inHours;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i had this problem i would solve saving the datetime of last two clicks on shared preferences or any database that you prefer, and on build method i would check if the older click has more than one day. if not i would disable the button and make a future.delayed function to able this buttom on right time. After the two clicks on 24h you need disable the button and make a future.delayed function to able the button after 24h. Just make sure to cancel the future function when the user change screen. A example of how cancel future.delayed function is here.

```
import 'dart:async';

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  final _cancelToken = CancelToken();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Cancel the scheduled task when the screen is disposed
    _cancelToken.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Execute Function X'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Schedule the task to run after 5 seconds
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), _executeFunctionX, cancelToken: _cancelToken);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _executeFunctionX() {
    // This function will only execute if the cancel token is not cancelled
    if (!_cancelToken.isCancelled) {
      // Code to execute
    }
  }
}
```